# Using scrollTop: tableRow.offset().top inside scrollable div, only showing distance from top of what's visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to use the animate function to scroll to a specific row of a table. It works fine when the scrollable div is at it's top, but when I scroll away from the top, then it only get the top of what is visible it seems.

I am using this inside a dialog (Bootstrap Modal window). Is there a way to get the distance from top of div not just what is visible?

HTML code below is part of a asp.net mvc4 Partial Class that goes into a Bootstrap Modal window (dialog box):

```
     <div id="LocationNumberModalAllLocations" style="Margin-top: -9px">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="row row-eq-height">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
         <div id="LocationNumberModalAllLocationsSelectionContainer"     class="ModalResultsTable">
          <table id="locationList" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
           <thead>
             <tr>
               <th>Location</th>
               <th>Items</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
           </tbody> 
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 modalTableColumnCanvas">
     <center><div id="control" style="Margin:-11px 0 5px 0">
        Go to location: <input type="text" size="10" id="GoToLocationInput"  /> <button onclick='gotoLocation()'> Go </button>
    </div></center>
       <div class="modalTableCanvas">
       <div class="ModalSelectedTable">       
       <center><h4>Selected Location's Inventory</h4></center>
       </div>
       <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>Part Number</th>
             <th>Condition</th>
             <th>Quantity</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
       <tbody>
       </tbody> 
     </table>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery code.

```
function gotoLocation() {

    //check if value exists
    var tableOfLocations = $('#locationList');
    var location = $('#GoToLocationInput').val();
    var tableRow = $('#locationList tbody tr td').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == location;
    });

    if (tableRow.length) {
        var container =   $('#LocationNumberModalAllLocationsSelectionContainer');
        var height = container.height();
        var tableRowPosition = tableRow.offset().top;
        container.animate({ scrollTop: tableRowPosition - (height / 2) }, 1000);
    }
}
```

SAMPLE:
jsfiddle.net/eaglei22/vgutew90

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well please?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Okay, I posted the html that is used with the function.

Comment: Copying your code exactly as is gives me `gotoLocation is not defined`. Do you encounter the same error?

Comment: No I do not get that, let me see if I can throw together a JSFiddle. Btw, I did find some sort of solution by first bringing the div to the top like so, container.scrollTop(0).. Calling that right before tableRowPosition is defined. The downside is even if it is already at that location is will scroll back from the top back to that location. It's not a bad solution, and I can probably just add some checks to see if input matches current table value.. but I still wonder why the reaction is what it is.

Comment: @ObsidianAge
https://jsfiddle.net/eaglei22/vgutew90/

There is my example. If you try going to 99, then going to 50, you will see it just scrolls back to the top when trying to go to 50. That is because the offset.top value is very small on the second attempt, which leads me to believe it's just grabbing it from the top of the div that is displayed on the screen. My solution does fix it, but just doesn't seem like the best solution. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a working solution for me, I don't know if it's the best, but it seems quick and does what I need it to. Here is the new Javascript:

```
function gotoLocation() {

    //check if value exists
    var tableOfLocations = $('#locationList');
    var location = $('#GoToLocationInput').val().trim().toUpperCase();


    if($("#Active").length)
    {
        var textVal = $("#Active").children().eq(0).text();
        if( textVal == location)
        {
          return;
        }
    }
    //remove old active row
    var tableRow = $('#locationList tbody').find('tr').removeAttr("id");
    tableRow.removeAttr("style");

    var tableRow = $('#locationList tbody tr td').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text().toUpperCase() == location;
    }).parent();

    tableRow.attr("id","Active");
    tableRow.css({'background-color': '#e8e8e8'});

    if (tableRow.length) {
        var container = $('#LocationNumberModalAllLocationsSelectionContainer');
        var height = container.height();
        container.scrollTop(0);
        var tableRowPosition = tableRow.offset().top;
        container.animate({ scrollTop: tableRowPosition - (height/1.5) }, 500);
    }
}
```

If requesting the same value that was last selected, nothing will happen. If requesting a new value table will scroll from top to matched row.